# Java Spring: mongodb connection issue

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven, dependencies

Earlier I used this spring-data-mongodb dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and now I changed to this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo]
```

Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myServlet-servlet.xml]

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:301)
```

I am unable to execute a single query. How can I fix this?

Comment: What exactly error  you are getting ? Please share sufficient logs

Answer (score 0):

This is the dependency that works for me:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: @lkhiloyalmokhai my project is spring mvc not boot